# long real arithmetics C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, bignum

I need to operate with numbers that contain 8 digits before the comma and 8 digits after comma, e.g. `12345678,12345678`.

How can I perform division, multiplication, and sum operations without loosing accuracy and I want to perform quick calculations.

What can you advice? I work in Visual Studio 2013, C#.

Comment: A long seems to fit your requirement... its range is `–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, thats 19 digits...

Comment: If you multiply two numbers that have 8 digits before and 8 digits after the decimal, your result (without loss of 'accuracy', whatever that means in your context) is 16 + 16 digits. And as for division - you will _almost always_ lose accuracy (just think about 1.0 / 3.0). You have to define what accuracy you are willing to accept in the final result. 15 digits is about all you will get with `double` - but if your system has a `long double` (128 bit) you're good to go. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx - VS2013 implements 80 bit `long double`.

Comment: Well I need that if I get number like 0,000000001 then it will be rounded to 0,00000001 (to the closest number that have 8 digits after comma and is bigger than result) so 1.0/3.0=0.33333334
Long Double is not enough, I need something that can store 8 deciaml digits.

Comment: System.Decimal can easily do it, accurate to 28 significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a datatype that can do what you want - [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), shortened to `decimal` in C#.

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

The range of numbers it supports is between negative and positive  79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335, and it supports 28-29 significant digits. Additionally, it supports all normal numerical operations (division, multiplication, etc) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use BigInteger type and store tne amount of integers after comma in separate integer.

```
BigInteger number1= new BigInteger(52793562305619195816059);
int amount1=10;
BigInteger number2=new BigInteger(568416843186432156843521);
int amount2=10;
BigInteger result=BugInteger.Mul(number1,numner2);
BigInteger remainder;
result=Biginteger.DivRem(result,amount1*amount2,remainder);
if (remainder>0)
result++;
```